# Do python "in" statements automatically return as true

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote this bit of unnecessarily complicated code on my way to learning about how to use the `in` statement to make `if` statements work better. I have two questions following the code snippet.

```
answer = ['Yes', 'yes', 'YES']
answer2 = ['No', 'no', 'NO']
ans = raw_input()
for i in range(0, 3):
    if ans in answer[i]:
        print "Yes!"
    elif ans in answer2[i]:
        print "No!"
    else:
        print "Don't know what that means"
```

First question: I think `if n in listname:` returns as True or False automatically. Does anyone know if that's the case?

Second question: the above code returns 3 lines that vary depending on if `ans` is actually in `answer` or `answer2`. I tried to eliminate that by replacing the relevant portions like so:

`if ans in answer[i] == True:`

This had the strange effect of making the code output only the `else:` statement. So can anyone explain to me the difference between how python interprets `if ans in answer[i]:` and `if ans in answer[i] == True:`, please?

Answer (score 15):

To answer your questions in reverse order, the reason why explicitly comparing with `True` did not work for you is that Python did not interpret the expression they way you expected. The Python parser has special handling of compare expressions so that you can chain them together and get a sensible result, like this:

```
>>> "a" == "a" == "a"
True
```

Notice that Python has to treat this whole thing as one operation, because if you split it into two operations either way you don't get the same result:

```
>>> ("a" == "a") == "a"
False
>>> "a" == ("a" == "a")
False
```

These behave differently because the part in the parentheses is evaluated first and returns `True`, but `True != "a"` so the whole expression returns false.

By rights the above shouldn't actually have any impact on your program at all. Unfortunately, Python handles `in` via the same mechanism as `==` so when you chain these together they are interpreted as a sequence like the above, so Python actually evaluates it as follows:

```
>> "a" in ["a"] == True
False
>>> ("a" in ["a"]) and ("a" == True)
False
```

It's wacky and arguably counter-intuitive, but that's unfortunately just how it works. To get the behavior you wanted you need to use parentheses to force Python to evaluate the first part separately:

```
>>> ("a" in ["a"]) == True
True
```

With all of that said, the `== True` is redundant because, as you suspected, the expression already returns a boolean and the `if` statement can just evaluate it as-is.

To return now to your other problem, I believe what you're trying to do is take one line of input and produce one corresponding line of output depending on what the user entered. You can apply the `in` operator to a string and a list to see if the string is in the list, which allows you to eliminate your `for` loop altogether:

```
answer = ['Yes', 'yes', 'YES']
answer2 = ['No', 'no', 'NO']
ans = raw_input()
if ans in answer:
    print "Yes!"
elif ans in answer2:
    print "No!"
else:
    print "Don't know what that means"
```

This first tests if the input matches any of the strings in `answer`, then the same for `answer2`. Of course, you could achieve a similar effect but also support other forms like `YeS` by simply converting the input to lowercase and comparing it to the lowercase form:

```
if ans.lower() == "yes":
    print "Yes!"
# (and so forth)
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as the difference between `ans in answer[i]` and `ans in answer[i] == True`, simple: Python expands the latter form out to `ans in answer[i] and answer[i] == True`, which is, of course, False since a string is not equal to `True`.

A simpler example may help illustrate this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> 2 in a
True
>>> 2 in a == True
False
>>> 2 in a and a == True
False
>>> (2 in a) == True
True
>>> 2 in a == [1, 2, 3]
True
>>> 2 in a and a == [1, 2, 3]
True
```

Notice how adding parentheses changes the behavior - this is akin to expansions like `1 < x < 5`, as opposed to `(1 < x) < 5`.

As a side note, it is generally considered poor style to explicitly check for `True` or `False` - it's much better to simply write `if x in y`.